# $R$-linear independence on free modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm going to give youy my definition of a *free module.*

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $M$ be a $R$-module. We say $M$ is free on $X$ if for every map $f: X \to N$ ($N$ a $R$-module) there exits a unique $\phi \in Hom_R(M,N)$ such that $$\phi \circ \iota = f $$
>   Where, $\iota: X \to M$.

It's easy to see from the uniqueness of $\phi$ that $\iota$ must be injective, however I was not able to prove that $\iota(X)$ is a $R$-lineraly independent subset of $M$.

**Note:** $X$ is not necessarily a subset of $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to treat $X$ as a subset of $M$ because it's easier. Suppose there is a nontrivial dependence relation
$$\sum a_xx=0$$
Then there is no module homomorphism
$$M\to\prod_{x\in X} R$$
such that the image of $X$ is independent. But there is a map from $X$  into the direct product whose image is independent.

Comment: How is this done when X is not a subset of M?

Comment: Like You can always treat $X$ like a subset of $M$ because you proved that the map is injective.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get the part "there is a map from $X$ to the direct product whose image is independent" which map? How is this a contradiction?

Comment: @Luke pick a nonzerodivisor element $r$ of $R$ and map $x$ to $\delta_xr$.